# Is overriding a function with derived class argument considered name hiding?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

I is this considered name hiding?
As according to the output it is:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){}
    virtual bool f(A& a) {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
    std::string s;
public:
    B(){}
    bool f(B& a) {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
        return s == a.s;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new B;
    B b;
    a->f(b);
}
```

This prints `A`, and if I want to achieve the polymorphic behaviour, I need to make the derived `class's f's` argument the same as the base classes. But in that case I don't have access to s in the derived class function. Is this a design deadlock or I am messing up the OOD principles?

Comment: virtual functions have to match how they are declared in the base class.  The only exception is the return type is allowed to be covariant.

Comment: It is a "design deadlock", because you are explicitly stating that `B::f()` will **not accept** an `A&` parameter.  So it can't be a runtime overload of `A::f(A&)`

Comment: @NathanOliver so the solution will be to pass A& to B::f and cast down?

Comment: If you write `bool f(B& a) override`, the compiler will tell you that you're not overriding.

Comment: demo of what moldbnilo said: https://godbolt.org/z/YYn9s4

Comment: @EduardRostomyan I'm not sure.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @EduardRostomyan The best solution in this kind of situation is usually to redesign. (This is a strong indication that your interface is broken.) "Double dispatch" (a.k.a. "the visitor pattern") might be a good idea.

Comment: If C++ allowed contravariant parameters in overrides, this still wouldn't be allowed. The contract set by the base class (which is the only thing clients are expected to have) is that any instance of `A` is allowed regardless of which derived type it is. For `B` to override that with a function that tightens that restriction with no way for the callers to know would be broken.

Comment: @NathanOliver so I have the hierarchy (A->B->C..) and on each level some additional data is added to corresponding class. I wans for each class answer whether 2 objects are the same or not (without any operators). And want all this with polymorphic manner (maintaining pointers to A). So is there a fancier solution than having all f functions accepting A& or A*and casting to corresponding type?

Comment: You *could* make all the functions take a `A&`, and then use `dynamic_cast` to figure out which actual type it is and then do the stuff you want but that is typically considered a design flaw.  This sounds more like a use case for a `std::variant` and using the visitor pattern, but I'm not sure how that would look in actual code.  The whole point of polymorphism is that you shouldn't have to care what the actual pointed to class.  The interface from the base class should provide all of the functionality you need.  If it can't then something else should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want multiple dispatch.

[Double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) pattern is a solution.

With c++17, we have `std::variant` which might do the dispatching for us:

```
class A;
class B;

using VariantA = std::variant<A*, B*, C*>;
using VariantConstA = std::variant<const A*, const B*, const C*>;

class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual VariantA AsVariant() { return this; }
    virtual VariantConstA AsVariant() const { return this; }

    friend bool operator==(const A&, const A&);
};

class B : public A
{
    std::string s;
public:
    B(std::string s) : s(s) {}
    VariantA AsVariant() override { return this; }
    VariantConstA AsVariant() const override { return this; }

    friend bool operator==(const B& lhs, const B& rhs);
};

// class C

struct EqualVisitor
{
    template <typename T>
    bool operator() (const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const { return lhs == rhs; }

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    bool operator() (const T1&, const T2&) const { return false; }
};


bool AreEqual(const A& lhs, const A& rhs)
{
    return std::visit(EqualVisitor{}, lhs.AsVariant(), rhs.AsVariant());
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4009de9fcb46029)